# What piece is this? It's a hard one, and a very small one. It's 2x1 I believe, and it could possibly be an accessory

Tags: part-identification, trains, micro-scale

[image]

This is the piece I'm looking for, because I'd like to build this microscale train myself. It may very well be the handles of two levers glued to the rest of the train, but I really don't want to believe whomever made this resorted to gluing their Legos. If anyone knows it's name or number I'd be quite grateful for any help.

Extra: If anyone knows the name or number of whatever small pieces are used for the other 3 wheels on the train, I also need to find out what those ones are. Thank you.

Comment: Incredible you put a circle around the piece, you wrote what it was, and I was still looking at the smoke and wondering how that could be made of the two lever pieces mentioned in the answer. Circles must be red? Anyway good question and good answer.

Answer (score 17):

You are partially correct, it is made using two of [Antenna Small Lever](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4593&C=11)
[image: Lever]
You can relax, they are not glued, but slotted into the grooves of the [1 x 2 Tile with grille](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2412b&C=85)
[image: Grille]
The other wheels of the train are made using [Minifigure Roller Skate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11253&C=11)
[image: Skate]

Comment: I'm confused about the roller skate wheels: I can see the part under the green cart. But is it also used for the tender and engine? If so, it would have to be turned 90 degrees, in which case the roller skate wheels would no longer be parallel to the tracks and it wouldn't look as nice from the other side.

Comment: @Emil the wagon wheels look smaller - so I wonder what's used for the engine/tender wheels if the wagons use the rollerskates

Comment: The engine and tender does use the rollerskate rotated by 90 degrees, and yes it wouldnt look good from the other side but… look at the rest of the image, see how much of the architecture is also one sided (the arches for example are one sided, the other side would show you the bent pole and clips, rather than the pseudo brick frontage…)

Comment: Bit of a cheat in that the "wheels" are attached to the tracks, and *not* to the train, so you can't push the train around the tracks easily.

Comment: Aw man that's so sad. It's really hard to find microscale lego builds that're both ridiculously small And functional. I do however thank you all for the help and am very glad that there's such a strong community for finding out what bricks things are

Comment: @Stephen the best way to thank someone for the help and effort they put into an answer is to Accept the answer that is the most helpful.

Comment: @ChrisH the wagon wheels might be the small end of binoculars

Comment: @JanWindemuth possibly as this is a one-sided build.  There are also  some smaller parts that aren't called binoculars but look like a compact pair, also used as robot wheels (can't identify them easily)